# javascript variable > than number

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am tying to find is:

"if div contains '(`a number greater than 1600` x `a number greater than 1063`)' alert success else alert error"

```
if (($('div:contains("(/*number greater than 1600*/ x /*number greater than 1063*/)")').length > 0)) {
    alert("SUCCESS");
}
else {
    alert("ERROR");
}
```

I thought I could use variables like

```
var w > 1600
var h > 1063
```

and then put them in like:

```
$('div:contains("('+ w + 'x' + h + ')")')
```

but that doesn't seem to work

Any ideas?

Comment: `:contains` just does string matching, it doesn't do arithmetic. Use `.filter()`.

Comment: *"that doesn't seem to work"* Yes. Even if the `var w > 1600` weren't a syntax error, you'd end up with a `:contains` selector that doesn't do anything like what you want it to do.

Comment: Is this a *specific* div, or are you searching for all matching divs?

Comment: browser does not understand ur magic spells.

Comment: Why is everyone down voting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to find all matching divs, you have to do a bit more work. Not a lot, but a bit:

```
var w = 1600;
var h = 1063;
// Find all divs and filter them
var matchingDivs = $("div").filter(function() {
    // Does this div's text match the form (1601 x 1064)?
    // If so, grab the numbers.
    var match = /^\((\d+) x (\d+)\)$/.exec($(this).text());
    if (match) {
        // Yes, it does, do the numbers fit?
        if (parseInt(match[1], 10) > w && // [1] = the first capture group
            parseInt(match[2], 10) > h) { // [2] = the second capture group
            // Keep this div
            return true;
        }
    }

    // Don't keep this div
    return false;
});
```

Comment: @user2768038: Then adjust as necessary. Parsing that is a very straight-forward application of regular expressions or even just `String#split`.

Comment: what happens if I have a load of divs? I only want one alert to whether a div on the page contains("(/*number greater than 1600*/ x /*number greater than 1063*/)") rather than saying yes that is true but it also isn't on all the other divs check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zrf6/2/)

Comment: @user2768038: You *use the result* of the above. `matchingDivs.length` will be the number of divs that matched. (You said you wanted to find "all" of them.) So...`alert("Matching divs: " + matchingDivs.length);` will show you how many matched, or `alert(matchingDivs.length ? "At least one div matched" : "No divs matched");` ir you don't want a count. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2zrf6/3/)

Comment: Sorry one last question. How would you go onto find the parent of the largest numbered div?

Comment: @user2768038: I think you need to fly solo from here. You have the numbers above, and of course the jQuery documentation tells you how to get the parent of an element.

Comment: I have got this [far](http://jsfiddle.net/2zrf6/6/) but I can't seem to get it to pick the largest value if I have two `span`s larger than said example? Could you help me from here. Don't worry if not. I have hassled you enough :)

Comment: could i turn it into an array and pick the last value from the array. As it would always be the last?

Answer (score 0):

If a div contains a number and nothing else, you can get it like this:

```
var num = Number($("#myDiv").text());
```

Or you can use the somewhat terser unary plus:

```
var num = +($("#myDiv").text());
```